# How to prevent modal from hiding vertical scroll bar

Tags: bootstrap-4

When opening the modal for 'login/register', the scroll bar is removed from the right of the screen.

I have the following code which prevent the content from shifting left on modal open, which is effective but the scroll bar is still removed and left with a white column:

```
.-modal-open .fixed,
.-modal-open .content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I tried to adding the following code, however this leaves me with 2 vertical scrolls bars:

```
.modal-open{
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

How can I keep the code that prevents the content shifting left whilst also keeping the scroll bar on show?

Live page: https://padder-939bc.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by playing with the different overflow settings in Chrome devtools.

Here's a video demo of how I found the solution you are looking for, which is:

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: overlay;
}
```

[image]